# Multiple form submits with RenderAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, renderaction

I am using `RenderAction` to include the form below in my views:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>" %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("form1", "UserControls", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form1" }))
{ %>
<div id="superDiv">Super User | Account:  <%= Html.DropDownList("dropdown", Model)%>
   <button type="submit" class="button">Button</button>
</div>
<% } %>
```

The problem is that when I have a form in a view eg:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Reports", "Report", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "reportForm", style= "display:none" }))
   { %>
   <%: Html.AntiForgeryToken()%>

  <%: Html.Hidden("reportType", null, new { @id = "reportType" }) %>
    <div class="middle"><button type="submit" class="button">Generate Report</button>
<% } %>
```

It will auto submit the form from `RenderAction`, how can this be prevented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use `Partial` instead of `RenderAction`

I use it to handle two forms (with 2 submit-buttons) on 1 page:

1st view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", FormMethod.Post)){...}
```

2nd view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post)) {...}
```

3rd main view:

```
<div style="...">
<div>
    @Html.Partial("Login")
</div>
<div>
    @Html.Partial("Register")
</div>
```

**upd:**

*I need to load data into the user control, and use it on multiple views/controls. How does that work with partial?*

You can create `Helper` that will accepts your data/params and renders by partial views

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyRegisterUserControl(this HtmlHelper html, SomeClass data)
    {
        //maybe some calculations here
        return html.Partial("Register", data);
    }
```

then you can use it in your views (something like that):

```
@Html.MyRegisterUserControl(new SomeClass(){...});
```

Comment: I need to load data into the user control, and use it on multiple views/controls. How does that work with partial?